# Tomcat Container Managed SSO Valve and Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, single-sign-on

We have over a dozen legacy web applications (each with their own app contexts) that use Tomcat's container managed security for simple form-based authentication.  We currently use Tomcat's single sign on valve to allow authenticated users to jump between web apps without the need of re-authenticating.  We are also developing new web applications using the Spring Security framework.

Is it possible to get users who are authenticated via the new Spring Security apps to also be able to jump to the older legacy (non-Spring) apps without the need of re-authenticating?  Is their a way to bridge Spring Security with the Tomcat SSO valve?

I prefer to avoid making any changes to the legacy web apps, but understand if it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 4):

You will be able to do it using J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e2766

Please note: 
When Tomcat SSO is configured it provides Java EE authentication for a web application.
It means that for an application is transparent if it was authenticated by form authentication or for Tomcat SSO. Finally it is Java EE authentication.
So, you need to use J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter to be able to use Java EE authentication provided by Tomcat.